# How to direct your java written program to write text in another program?

Tags: java, eclipse, textbox

I'm new to this very useful site... so I would give my thanks to every one upon here:
about a month i started to learn Java programming through Eclipse after i been learning C# for about 2 years, i started Java cause i knew I can develop Apps and Games and put them out into the the open source market (Playstore)...

So i wrote an simple program in Java Eclipse , it takes your facebook and hotmail..etc IDs and passwords and tells you to give a short master password and ID that would help me avoid keyloggers and shorten my time typing my long ID and pass.
this program passes through these levels:
1) You run the program
2) It tells you to add a PROGRAM or a WEBSITE for an editable list.
2.1) It takes the inputs ( i mean the ID and pass ) for every object you add into the list.
3) Then you go back to the main tab in the program, and there shows 2 textboxes one for The short ID and another for short pass. and below the list of programs/websites list to choose which one you want to sign into..

**WHAT I'M ASKING:
When I tell my java program to run a program, I can't find a way to direct commands to that programs to write your real password and email ID into the textboxes... example: Windows Live Messenger... What can I do? can you write me a useful code? it seems to be different bit from C#...
p.s - I know how to run a program in java but I don't know how to direct commands in a program.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suppose you want to pass parameters to external programs...

this is one way to do this :

```
public class Runner{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String[] cmd = { "C:\\Program Files\\MY PROGRAM.exe","PARAM1","PARAM2" };
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    System.out.println("Done.");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much... it really helped me... but one last thing how can i do it for running and passing parameters to .apk extension type.. and if you want to run it on android OS? and please if you want tell me simplified explanation for the (throws Exception)... and i noticed the colors you use (blue,sky,red,black) in what you type.. what do these color indicate for? i know i'm talking too much but do as much as you want if want to do me a favor.